# Issues with rsyslog configuration

Tags: linux, rsyslog

I'm trying to config a RSYSLOG server to receive logs from my other machine, by having my conf file inside /etc/rsyslog.d/my.conf

**file: my.conf**

> ```
> source s_net { udp(ip(192.168.0.1) port(514)); };
> filter VM01{ host( "192.168.0.2" ); };
> destination df_VM01 { file("/var/log/my.log"); };
> log { source ( s_net ); filter( VM01 ); destination ( df_VM01 ); };
> ```

**file:rsyslog.conf:**

```
    # rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

# The imjournal module bellow is now used as a message source instead of imuxsock.
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
#$ModLoad imklog # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
#*.* @@remote-host:514
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###

# provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
```

After I restarted the rsyslog service I started to receive these errors:
    CONFIG ERROR: could not interpret master config file '/etc/rsyslog.conf'. [v8.24.0-34.el7_6.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/my.conf, on or before line 1: warnings occured in file '/etc/rsyslog.d/my.conf' around line 1

I searched the error online and it is referring to this message:
"The error most often actually is on the quoted line, or at least very close in front of it"

I don't have quoted lines and my Linux experience is low, that's why I was trying to learn a little bit more, but now I'm stuck with this error.

Any thoughts????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any thoughts????

Your `my.conf` file appears to use syslog-ng syntax instead of what rsyslog supports.

It's a bit of a read, but I recommend starting at page 1 and working your way through the manual here: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/. I did that myself a few years back and learned a lot from doing so.

It's been a while since I read it, but I recall this resource being useful as well:

https://sematext.com/blog/rsyslog-ebook-centralized-logging-with-rsyslog/